AssertionError: RequestValidationError not raised for FastAPI route testing
I have a pytest test case that tests fastapi post API call. The call raises validation_error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/\_exception_handler.py", line 44, in wrapped_app
await app(scope, receive, sender)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 70, in app
response = await func(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 291, in app
raise validation_error
fastapi.exceptions.RequestValidationError: ...........

In my test code
with self.assertRaises(fastapi.exceptions.RequestValidationError):
    test_client.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=json)

So I expected to suppress the RequestValidationError.
But I saw failed message as
AssertionError: RequestValidationError not raised
I also tried the generic ValidationError
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
it did not work.

FastAPI has internal exception handlers, as you can see in: Handling Errors

When a request contains invalid data, FastAPI internally raises a RequestValidationError.
And it also includes a default exception handler for it.

So, in your case, you should expect an HTTP response, not an exception:
response = test_client.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=json)

assert response.status_code == expected_status_code


Thanks Rafael for the answer. The provided link "Handling Errors" cannot be accessed.

Sorry Sam, fixed it.
